# Swift keep pointer/reference to object or another a pattern?

Tags: ios, swift

I am converting a project from another tool and language:

Suppose I have a

```
singleimagecache: UIImage;
```

I now pass this to a structure which does

```
var myimage: UIImage = singleimagecache;
```

Now, this struct is passed to a function that does some work.

This function determines another image should be cached. In my original code, it would simply use **myimage** and assign its **content** some other image-bitmap data. Since the object-reference itself was not changed (only its content) **singleimagecache** would still point to valid fresh new cache data.

However, this is not possible in Swift since UIImage requires to be reconstructed like this:

```
myimage = UIImage(...)
```

But doing that would leave **singleimagecache** with wrong data

So that leaves me the following options:

- Any support in Swift for keeping references in sync?
- Any support in Swift for keeping pointers to objects (that themselves possibly can be nillable)
- Wrap UIImage inside another object that is persistant and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in Swift support for what you wish to do. I would just make a wrapper class with 2 UIImage properties. One would be **myimage** and the other would be **singleimagecache**. You could then use the **didSet** property observer on **myimage** to achieve the desired synchronization so that **singleimagecache** will always be up to date with **myimage**. **didSet** will be called everytime a new value is stored/set in the property.

```
class imageCache
    {
       var myimage:
 = UIImage() {
          didSet {
            singleimagecache = myimage
          }
       }
       var singleimagecache = UIImage()
    }
```